# Help integrate 1/sin²(x)

Tags: calculus, integration

i need help to integrate $\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} dx$. I tried integration by parts $u = \sin²x$ and $dv=1$ but still don't got an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin^2x}=\int\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan^2x}\ dx$$

Set $\tan x=u$

Comment: Nice move(+1). Then spot it's a "chain rule backwards" as the derivative of $\tan x$ is $\sec^2 x$.

Answer (score 1):

What is the derivative of $\cot(x)$?